# Compile VLCKit as static framework for iOS

Tags: objective-c, vlc, libvlc, tvos

I have a question. I cloned VLCKit from (http://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit.git) and try to compile as static framework for tvOS (params -f -t). But I can't find compiled framework (expecting .framework file). Where is it?

Answer (score 1):

The framework flag is not available for tvOS at the moment. For tvOS we only provide a universal static library (*.a) with headers (universal in the sense that it includes a slice for the simulator as well as the device).

Comment: Hi Guys I've been trying to to this for days now, if you managed it I have an open freelancer project to achieve just this, TVVLCKit.framework that I can use in a project and archive from Xcode here is the freelancer if you fancy making a few $$$ i'd be willing to pay about $50 https://www.freelancer.co.uk/projects/Mobile-Phone/Compile-TVVLC-framework-MobileVLCKIt/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the compile process is broken because tvOS and iOS versions don't match: after compiling using tvOS 9.1, it complains about missing 9.0 SDK:

```
[info] Building MobileVLCKit (MobileVLCKit, Release, iphoneos)
xcodebuild: error: SDK "iphoneos9.0" cannot be located.
```

I am not very confident in understanding the compilation prices but it appears that the last phase must hardcode the compilation directories and *apparently* set a bad target but also use this information as the base SDK so I added a new parameter like below:

buildxcodeproj MobileVLCKit "TVVLCKit" phones **appletvos9.0**

buildxcodeproj MobileVLCKit "TVVLCKit" iphonesimulator **appletvsimulator9.0**

that replace the value for --sdk of xcodebuild in buildxcodeproj

Further the paths in final lipo commands are wrong

hope that helps

Comment: @feepk could you look into this again ? I've been trying to compile the framework for tvos for a couple of days now without success. This build script doesn't work either: https://gist.github.com/fbradyirl/8dcc1674c87a9067a356

Comment: sorry. i just forgot to add all the frameworks. works great. thanks for all your work feepk!

Comment: Hi Guys I've been trying to to this for days now, if you managed it I have an open freelancer project to achieve just this, TVVLCKit.framework that I can use in a project and archive from Xcode here is the freelancer if you fancy making a few $$$ i'd be willing to pay about $50 https://www.freelancer.co.uk/projects/Mobile-Phone/Compile-TVVLC-framework-MobileVLCKIt/